# TypeScript library types definition

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write my own library definition for an open source project (https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver-JavaScript-API), but i'm stuck.

I've managed to clone the repo, and to write the types for the `bimserverapipromise.js` module, so now i have the `bimserverapipromise.d.ts` ([gist](https://gist.github.com/GiacomoManzoli/8f5d3375c890eb698ba9eb67ca11c976)) and i can write:

```
// index.ts
import BimServerApiPromise from "BimServerApiPromise";
let x = new BimServerApiPromise();
```

The troubles starts with the `bimserverclient.js` module, where the same approach doesn't work: i made a `bimserverclient.d.ts` with the definitions ([gist](https://gist.github.com/GiacomoManzoli/f09929a9d3d7f4dd4eca2df85a973180)), but the compiler seems unable to load the module.

```
// index.ts
import BimServerClient from "BimServerClient";  // VSCode error: module not found
let y = new BimServerClient();
```

The folder structure of the project is:

```
|- /index.ts
|- /tsconfig.json
|_ /BIMServerJavaScriptApi/bimserverclient.d.ts
|_ /BIMServerJavaScriptApi/bimserverclient.js
|_ /BIMServerJavaScriptApi/bimserverapipromise.d.ts
|_ /BIMServerJavaScriptApi/bimserverapipromise.js
|_ /BIMServerJavaScriptApi/** other files **
```

The `tsconfig.json` is the following:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "listFiles": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es2016", "dom"]
    },
    "include": [
        "./**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

What am i missing? it's something due to the multiple `import/export` of the `bimserverclient.js` module, or perhaps it's because the type definition covers only one part of the JS module export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `BimServerClient` behaves differently than `BimServerApiPromise` is that your `declare module 'BimServerClient'` statement appears in a file with a top-level import, so it is being treated as a module augmentation instead of a module declaration.  You could fix that by moving the `import BimServerApiPromise from 'BimServerApiPromise';` inside the `declare module 'BimServerClient' { ... }` block.

However, a bigger question is whether it is correct to declare modules named `BimServerClient` and `BimServerApiPromise` in the first place.  These names won't work to import the JavaScript modules at runtime unless the calling project sets up some special module loader or bundler configuration.  I'd suggest removing the `declare module` statement and just putting the contained declarations at the top level of the file.  Then any import that resolves to one of the JavaScript files according to normal Node.js module resolution rules will automatically pick up the corresponding `.d.ts` file for TypeScript.  For your file layout, the correct relative import path to use from `index.ts` would be `./BIMServerJavaScriptApi/bimserverclient` and/or `./BIMServerJavaScriptApi/bimserverclient.js` (depending on your module loader or bundler), whereas if you were to install `BIMServerJavaScriptApi` as an npm package at `node_modules/bimserverapi`, you would use the non-relative import path `bimserverapi/bimserverclient` and/or `bimserverapi/bimserverclient.js` or simply `bimserverapi` (relying on the `main` field of `package.json`).  If you are having trouble with your imports, please update the question and I will be happy to help further.

Comment: That worked, thanks! So for the local development it's easier to avoid the module definition. But, what if i want to publish the definitions on DefinitelyTyped? In that case i should use the `module` syntax with the inner `import` statement, right?

Comment: On DefinitelyTyped, you still have to structure the definitions to match the way people will import the implementation modules.  If someone imports `bimserverapi/bimserverclient` and the implementation is found at `node_modules/bimserverapi/bimserverclient.js`, then TypeScript will look at `node_modules/@types/bimserverapi/bimserverclient.d.ts` (as well as `node_modules/bimserverapi/bimserverclient.d.ts`) for the type declarations.  So if you create a DefinitelyTyped package named `@types/bimserverapi` and put `bimserverclient.d.ts` in the root of the package, then things should work.